# Android how to do Video chat between two devices?

Tags: android, videochat

I am trying to develop sample video chat application in android.
 I have reviewed the sample projects like "**sipdroid**","**Tango**" which works with the support of **sipserver**. 
but i dont want to develop with the support of sipserver.
i want to develop the sample application like "*Fring*" android app. 
how to do ?? please provide me some guidelines. 
i am hoping for an good response. Thanks in advance ..